# Disk Utilization with DriveInfo[]

Tags: c#

EDIT 9:20am CST: It appears you just have to convert

```
   if (d.Name == drvNamefrm2)
```

to

```
    if (d.Name == (string)drvNamefrm2)
```

---

Alright, I am trying to write a small performance monitor. I've done research on here and worked through some walk-thrus. This is probably a small problem with an easy fix, but I can't see it. I was hoping you could take a look.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;


namespace TrafcLightPerfMeter_v1
  {
public partial class diskUtilForm : Form
{
```

It uses two forms and I am bringing over the initial selection from Form1 hence the parameters in the form name below.

```
    public diskUtilForm(int drvNumfrm1, string drvNamefrm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainForm test = new mainForm();
        **object drvNumfrm2 = (object)drvNumfrm1;
        object drvNamefrm2 = (object)drvNamefrm1;
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

It's this "foreach" section. It is skipping over my "if" even if the d.Name is == to drvNamefrm2 --  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

The idea here is "if" they match "then" the traffic light background will be green. Then I want to use that little formula to designate the rest of the colors. I just need it to enter the if statement.

```
   foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
         if (d.Name == drvNamefrm2)
            {
                labelGreen.BackColor = Color.Green;
                long totalAvailable = d.AvailableFreeSpace;
                long totalSpace = d.TotalSize;

        double percentAvailable =   Math.Round(((double)totalAvailable/(double)totalSpace)*100,4);**

            }
        }

    }
}
 }
```

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: What's the type of `drvNamefrm2`? The name suggests a control, but you're comparing as a string.

Comment: I am bringing in the drvNamefrm1 (from my Form1 into my Form2) -- that's just a way I am distinguishing them.

Comment: Right. I had to go an convert drvNamefrm2 to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just have to convert

```
if (d.Name == drvNamefrm2)
```

to

```
if (d.Name == (string)drvNamefrm2)
```

--The formula also appears to be working now. So, later own I can do comparison and color changing on the "traffic light".